# Unrecognized field: id while trying to login with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

The registration form is custom and it works, meanwhile no modification within login part. When I tried to login I get the error as the title says.

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: "Unrecognized field: id" at project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php line 101
```

Actually I don't have an `id` column in my `users` table, instead `user_key` is used. As follows is what the table looks like.

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_key              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username_canonical    | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email                 | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email_canonical       | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| enabled               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

      ....some other columns 
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And my userEntity comes as below.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints= {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_key_UNIQUE", columns={"user_key"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_key", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $userKey;
                .
                .
                .

 }
```

Any idea to help me on this? 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks to the advice of @Artamiel and @Richard, I changed the PK to id and all solved, huh, currently for this thread.

Comment: Your `BaseUser` uses `$this->id` for serialization. There is also a getter that you need to override. Also, check if you overridden the `UserProvider`, since there is a `findBy(array('id')). Take a look at the [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946344/unrecognized-field-id-while-trying-to-login-with-fosuserbundle)

Comment: Make your life easier and just use id,  unless you have to do a massive amount of refactoring.

Comment: @Artamiel thanks mate I didn't do anything with the serialization I think I should but didn't know where to do.

Comment: @Richard Nice. I'm feeling easier ;D

Comment: You better take that advice from me and @Richard. Unless you really have a solid reason for using different `PK`, stick to the original name. There really is no point wasting time for something like that.

Comment: @Artamiel Ya I did it. Actually in this case there are several tables needs to be joined, that's the original thought of using userKey. Anyway id is different from others and worth a special treat. I learned that thank you guys.